# Automatic installation of the extension from the site?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, codeigniter-3

I need to make a website with automatic installation of the plugin. Can anyone suggest a library or a better method from it that will provide access to browser extensions so that you can implement this functionality?

Comment: Extension installation will always require user's permission. The browser won't even download it before the user accepts it. You can automate the request popup on page load, but you cannot do more than that.

Comment: In general, the idea is: "The user clicks the" Install "button, and after that the installation of this plugin takes place." Could you show the realization of such a thing, if it is not difficult?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support inline installation of extensions anymore, but https://www.themebeta.com/ uses a workaround that still works - see how they're doing it.

Comment: So this is not an extension, or did I misunderstand something?